# Issue with Loading athena tables from multiple zip files in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a requirement to create an Athena table from multiple zip files of multiple folders in S3.

I have a folder structure in S3 as follows: S3 bucket==>Clients folder==> multiple folders for multiple countries like (US, JAPAN,UK... till 50 countries) ==> 10 to 50 '.gz' files in each country folder

I need to merge all the '.gz' files from all the region folders and create a single table in S3, i used the glue crawlers and classifiers but the files are not getting merged into table.

Please help me with other ways to create a table 'companies_all_regions' on Athena from all the files

Comment: To clarify... Are you saying that the folder structure is `client1/us`, `client1/japan`, `client2/us`, etc? And you want to query across all of those 'folders' for all clients combined? Question: Are there any other files in the client-level folders, or are _all_ the files contained at the country-level? Are all files in exactly the same format? Also (and most importantly), are there _any_ other files _anywhere_ in that bucket that do _not_ contain the data you want to query?

Comment: Hi John, Yes the folder structure is as you mentioned: client1/us or japan or uk ..../files for each country. I wanted the table merged from all folders files. No, there are no other files separately and all files are at each country level. All files are csv.gz format with columns separated by comma. Am facing issue with declaring schema in classifier as there are commas in column also which is splitting that column into multiple columns which is not wanted. I need to declare that column with escape character as 'comma' and separator as 'comma' and merge all files into single table.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Amazon Athena external table at the top-level of the bucket. All files at that level, and in sub-folders, will be included in the table. All files will need to be in the same format.

If your CSV files contain commas *within* a column, then the values for the column would need to be placed "inside double quotes".

If you are able to change the way the files are created, you could choose an alternate column separator, such as the pipe (`|`) character. That will avoid problems with commas inside field values. You can then configure the table to use the pipe as the separator character.

Comment: I can create a table on Athena using the table DDL but i need to automate the process by creating a table for each client as i have multiple client folders going to be added in future. Could you please suggest me how i could set that load automated

Comment: I am now confused. You said "I wanted the table merged from all folders files", but now you are saying "a table for each client". Are you wanting a _single_ table, or are you wanting _one table per client_? Or, are you seeking a single table that also contains a column with the client name, so you can separate the data on a per-client basis?

Comment: Hi John, yes as of now there is only one client who will add data in 'client X' folder but going forward we will be getting many clients or agents data like 'client y, client z' which will be of above structure as folders of countries and  files for each country. How can i automate this process of creating a combined table every time a new client folder gets added in my bucket

Comment: If you are only wanting one table that includes _all data from every client and every subdirectory_, then simply create the table with the top-level of the bucket as the `location`. It will automatically include all files in every subdirectory.

Comment: Actually i tried creating table using Glue crawler but the table is created as partitions and i cant see any data in the table. Is glue crawler the only way to automatically load data into athena, please suggest me on automating the table load

Comment: You can write your own [`CREATE TABLE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html) statement in Athena. They can be a little complex to get the right format, so the Glue crawler is easier. To view what the crawler did, go to Athena, click the 3-dots next to the table name and select **Generate Create Table DDL**.  Please add it to your Question so we can see how it attempted to create the table.

Comment: Does Glue have a solution so that it will create tables with the escape character and serde formatting setup for csv files to create athena tables?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Glue will crawl the existing files to 'guess' at the file format and will create a table in the Glue Catalog, which Athena uses. If you are having a particular problem with Glue, please add the details to your Question, or create a new Question.